# Exporting shapefiles to NetCDF Format using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, netcdf

I'm completely new to using GIS but I've got some shapefiles that I really need in NetCDF format for further analysis.

Does anyone know if this is possible in QGIS?

I know that you can do this using NCL but unfortunately it is not installed on the system I'm working from.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which explains how our "Focused question/Best answer" model operates, and emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Both ArcGIS and QGIS can work with NetCDF, so this is, in effect, two questions. I suggest your research your options, choose one software package, and make an attempt to convert the data. Then, if you run into a problem, you can document that as a question.

Answer (score 2):

QGIS can *read* NetCDF vector files but has no visible support for *writing* them at the moment: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/30492

You can use GDAL's `ogr2ogr` though:

```
ogr2ogr -F netCDF output.nc input.shp
```

Make sure you throughly read through https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/netcdf.html so that your output is not accidently broken or misleading.